# Trigger cell value change in Excel based on the drop down selected

Tags: c#, excel

I'm developing a project which requires to read the selected value from the drop down list and generate the values for other cells in the Excel.

Below is a snippet from the code:

```
var list = new System.Collections.Generic.List<string>();
list.Add("A");
list.Add("B");
list.Add("C");
var flatList = string.Join(",", list.ToArray());

var cell = ws.get_Range("D1", Type.Missing);
cell.Validation.Delete();
cell.Validation.Add(
XlDVType.xlValidateList,
XlDVAlertStyle.xlValidAlertInformation,
XlFormatConditionOperator.xlBetween,
flatList,
Type.Missing);

cell.Validation.IgnoreBlank = true;
cell.Validation.InCellDropdown = true;
cell.Value = "Overall";
```

I used the above code and was successfully able to create a dropdown list. But I am not sure how to read the value that is selected. Based on the value selected, the cell D3 value should be updated. I need a code somewhat like this:

```
if(selected option is "A")
{
  Cell D3 value should be ="111";
}
else if (selected option is "B")
{
 cell D3 value should be ="222";
}
else
{
  cell D3 value should be ="333";
}
```

How can cell value change be triggered based on the value selected in dropdown?

Answer (score 0):

In excel, drop down value resides in cell hence you just have to get the cell value on which you have applied drop down list.

You just need the below code to read value from cell:

```
var cellValue = (string)(ws.Cells[4, 1] as Excel.Range).Value;
```

Then you can use conditional `IF ELSE` to check cell value and do the needful.

```
if(cellValue == "A")
{
   //Do something
}
else if(cellValue == "B")
{
   //Do something
}
```

and so on...

Comment: Hi paresh,Thanks for your answer. But this only reads the cell value of the drop down list. I want to change the value of another cell based on the value selected in the drop down list. I used event handlers in this case.
xl.EnableEvents = true;
            EventDel_CellsChange = new Excel.DocEvents_ChangeEventHandler(CellsChange1);
            ws.Change += EventDel_CellsChange;

 public static void CellsChange1(Excel.Range target)
    {

Answer (score 0):

To Paresh J:

Good anwsers, but there is a little mistake.

```
var cellValue = (string)(ws.Cells[1, 4] as Excel.Range).Value;
```

I think "Cells[1, 4]" equals "get_Range("D1", Type.Missing)".